# Where do matrices of real numbers lie?

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces, notation

I have a question on the space where matrices of real numbers lie. Suppose I have a vector $x$ of real numbers with dimension $p\times 1$. I usually write $x\in \mathbb{R}^p$. Consider now a matrix $X$ of real numbers of dimension $p\times n$. Where does this matrix lie?

Comment: Are you asking for a _notation_ for the set of all $p\times n$ matrices with real entries?

Comment: I guess you mean https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_%28mathematics%29#Notation
where $m$ instead of $p$ is used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The set of matrices which size is $p\times m$ is denoted in different ways in mathematics. For instance I use $M_{p,m}(\mathbb{R})$. Another notation is $\mathbb{R}^{p\times m}$, which means vectors where every components lies in $\mathbb{R}^m$.